# Updating a list of actions just before user clicking

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile, flutter-listview

I have a list of actions in a listview and updating every 5 seconds. User can click one of the actions. The problem is, sometimes listview could be updated just before the user click. Thus causing the user to click on a different item they want to click. What should I do in that case? Measure the pased time between listview update and user click, if it is too short then cancel the click. What would your solution be in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is valid, you can reassign a `DateTime.now()` when there's an update and check the difference in the `onTap()`. Or you can replace the `ListView` with a `CircularProgressIndicator` while updating. If the update is sub-second, you can add an `await Future.delayed(Duration())`.

Comment: yes, that's probably the only way. I was wondering if there was any other work done on this problem. In the last case, I also checked whether the index of the clicked item has changed. If the index has not changed, it executes the click normally, if it has changed it ignores the click.